# base64 gzip decompression in R

Tags: r, base64, gzip, compression

I get from an API a *base64 gzip compressed string* and want to decompress it in R.

**input**: a compressed base64 gzip string

**output**: decompressed string

tried out:

```
string <- "H4sIAAAAAAAA/3OtSMwtyEmNLy4pysxLjy/Jj09JTc7PLShKLS6OTyvKz41PSixONTOJT6/KLOACAIKC50YuAAAA"

datadecompressed <-  memDecompress(from = charToRaw(string),type = c('gzip'))
```

Error: `Error in memDecompress(from = charToRaw(string), type = c("gzip")) : 
  internal error -3 in memDecompress(2)`

It works perfectly fine in Python:

```
import gzip, base64

comp = "H4sIAAAAAAAA/3OtSMwtyEmNLy4pysxLjy/Jj09JTc7PLShKLS6OTyvKz41PSixONTOJT6/KLOACAIKC50YuAAAA"    
decomp = gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(comp))
print(comp)
print(decomp)
```

...but unfortunately I need it in R.
Thank you in advance

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600738/how-can-i-unzip-a-base64-encoded-string-in-r